# Utilizing argument within profile fetch

Tags: php

I have a function within my `DUser` Class that I would like to accept arguments.

```
        public function UserProfile($arg) {
                $query = <<<SQL
                SELECT firstName,lastName
                FROM {$this->tprefix}profile
                WHERE id = :thissession
SQL;
            $resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );
            $resource->execute( array (
            ':thissession'  => $_SESSION['id'],
            ));
            foreach($resource as $row) {
                $this->firstname = $row['firstName'];
                $this->lastname = $row['lastName'];
            }
            switch($arg) {
                case 'firstname':
                echo $this->firstname;
                break;
                case 'lastname':
                echo $this->lastname;
                break;
            }
        }
```

With this I want a user to be able to run

```
<?php $users = new DUser();
$users->UserProfile("firstname");
```

And it would return the firstname of the user that's currently logged in, I've looked this over and I thought for sure it would work, but when used it returns no data. Not an error or anything, just no data at all. =/ If someone sees anything wrong with the way this is written it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$this->db->db->prepare` 2x db seems a bit weird; Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing a query, but you're not FETCHING the results using one of the PDO methods like PDOStatement::fetch() or ::fetchAll(). Optional arguments for this method are if you want object or array and so on.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

```
$resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );// YOU SURE IS db->db->prepare()???
$resource->execute( array (
       ':thissession'  => $_SESSION['id'],
        ));

$result =  $resource->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //This does the magic
foreach($result as $row) {
    $this->firstname = $row['firstName'];
    $this->lastname = $row['lastName'];
}
```

**EDIT:** Seeing that it should return a single result, I would use the method fetch() which returns the contents of the next row of a statement, in this case, a single row result.

```
$result =  $resource->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //This does the magic
$this->firstname = $result['firstName'];
$this->lastname= $result['lastName'];
```

Comment: There's actually no need for the `resource->fetch` when I run `foreach($resource as $row)` Appreciate the input, but the issue lied in the fact that I hadn't added anything to the MySQL database and had forgotten to assign defaults, so it returned nothing because well. There was nothing to return. I appreciate the input though! And yes I'm sure it's `db->db->prepare` that way I can change it to `db->sitedb` `db->otherdb` later on if need be.

Comment: Hahahaha, well then!! Shit happens :P